# International layover - do I need to go through immigration and customs?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, international-travel, layovers, atlanta

I am looking into flights from Tokyo to Bogotá. The layover is in ATL - Hartsfield-Jackson. Do I need to go through immigration and customs if I am not going to stay in ATL or the US? Both flights with same airline, KLM.

Comment: Same airline? Just two flights? There is something strange. But attention: KLM could flight also in Caribbean, then to Bogota, but Nederland has territories there, so you risk to go "domestic" at AMS. Note: KLM is in the same alliance of Delta, ATL is the hub of Delta.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi as far as I know, Dutch islands in the Caribbean are not part of the Schengen area.  That is certainly the case for Curaçao; I'm not sure about all of the islands.  But it doesn't seem to make much sense to fly from Tokyo to Bogotá via Europe. The closest major non-US airport to the [great circle route](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=NRT-BOG) appears to be Vancouver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike most civilized countries, ALL passengers coming through US airports must go through US immigration and through security checks again. This applies at all US airports.

Comment: This, of course, means that arriving non-US passengers must have a visa or ESTA (or be Canadian or other small exceptions).

Comment: @GregHewgill yes, thanks. Forget to add the basics sometimes hah.

Comment: That is just insane. I have lots of experience going through customs and immigration in the US since I lived there for 10 years, and unless one goes through a small airport, it is a nightmare - and the longest line I ever had to endure was in ATL. I was always entering the US, not passing through.

It's just ridiculous to make all passing-through travelers go through the whole process just to board the next plane... I guess I'd better look for a different route.

Comment: @cVergel Yeah, it is quite ridiculous. An alternate route would likely save you an unnecessary headache!

Comment: @cVergel if you have a short connection, an airline employee will likely take you to the front of the line.  I've never entered the US through ATL, though (I live near JFK), so I can't comment on the experience there.  I also have never used the kiosks, so I can't comment on how they've affected the throughput of the immigration control checkpoint.

Comment: An exception to the rule stated by @Ozzy above is if the travelers has passed through a US Immigration and Customs Precelearance Facility, found at many Canadian airports, Dublin, the Bahamas, and the UAE. If travelers pass through a Preclearance facility, they will arrive in the US as domestic passengers, and will exit the plane directly into baggage claim and the airport's arrival hall.